# Does using nested queries adds semantics to the sql query over simple query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, having

```
   create table students(id int,
   name varchar(20),
   dept varchar(10),
   salary int default 10000
   );

Insert into students values(1,'Ram','HR',10000);
Insert into students values(2,'Amrit','Mrkt',20000);
Insert into students values(3,'Ravi','HR',30000);
Insert into students values(4,'Raju','finance',40000);
```

Query which my tutor told me:

```
select name from employee where dept in(select dept from emp group by dept having count(*)<2);
```

he told that we should only use that attribute with select statement which has been used in group by and other attributes cannot be used.

But the following query also works:

```
select name from employee group by dept having count(*)<2;
```

is my query correct or wrong? if it is correct what is the advantage of using it as nested query than simple query?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one matching row, then you can use:

```
select max(name)
from employee
group by dept
having count(*) = 1;
```

The `having` clause guarantees one match.  The `max()` returns the value in the one row.

This is fine, but not very orthodox -- it doesn't generalize very well.  The form that your tutor suggests is more generalizable.  It will readily adapt to looking for employees in departments with 2 employees or 7 or whatever.